Why does Blob() yield a different result with an Array than with a Uint8Array?
Why does Blob() yield different results between passing an Array and a Uint8Array, when all values represent raw bytes?
new Blob([[0,60,0,60]])
// Blob {size: 9, type: ''}

new Blob([new Uint8Array([0,60,0,60])])
// Blob {size: 4, type: ''}


"when all values represent raw bytes?" Are you sure that 60 is represented as a byte in JavaScript? In other words, why would JavaScript, given an Array of Numbers, choose to store those Number values as bytes?

The question is very clear. It has nothing to do with bit shifting. It is more about how Blob is specified and hence implemented.

@pilchard no, that's absolutely unrelated

TL;DR

Passing an Array of numbers ([[0,60,0,60]]) to the Blob constructor converts them to strings.

"0,60,0,60" size = 9


Passing an Uint8Array (new Uint8Array([0,60,0,60])) to the Blob constructor results in an internal BufferArray that represents the given Bytes.

[0, 60, 0, 60] size = 4



Explanation
The first Blob constructor parameters (W3) (blobParts) only support three different types:

BufferSource elements
Blob elements
USVString elements

Input breakdown (Array)


const blob = new Blob([[0, 60, 0, 60]]);
console.log({ size: blob.size, type: blob.type });




The outer array [] is the blobParts sequence.
The inner array [0, 60, 0, 60] is a regular JavaScript array of numbers.
Regular Array of numbers: This is neither a BufferSource, Blob, nor a USVString. When the constructor encounters an unsupported type, it converts it to a string using the default toString() method (read 3 and 4).
Serialization: [0, 60, 0, 60].toString() results in the string "0,60,0,60".



console.log([0,60,0,60].toString())
console.log([0,60,0,60].toString().length)




The string "0,60,0,60" is treated as a USVString, encoded in UTF-8.
Size Calculation: Each character (including commas) occupies 1 byte in UTF-8, totaling 9 bytes.

Input breakdown (Uint8Array)


const blob = new Blob([new Uint8Array([0,60,0,60])])
console.log({ size: blob.size, type: blob.type });




The array [new Uint8Array([0, 60, 0, 60])] is the blobParts sequence.
Uint8Array is a BufferSource.
BufferSource is an ArrayBuffer where each element corresponts to one byte. It is "An object that holds a pointer (which can be null) to a buffer of a fixed number of bytes"
Size Calculation: [0, 60, 0, 60] results in 4 bytes.



console.log(new Uint8Array([0,60,0,60]))
console.log(new Uint8Array([0,60,0,60]).length)




The Blob constructor does not take an array of arrays as its argument. It takes an array of binary values - those might be buffers, blobs, typed arrays, or strings, but not arrays. The array you are passing is converted to a string, whose 9 characters are put as bytes into the blob:


(async() => {
  console.log(new Uint8Array(await new Blob([[0,60,0,60]]).arrayBuffer()));
  console.log(new Uint8Array(await new Blob(["0,60,0,60"]).arrayBuffer()));
  /*
    0: 48 // '0'
    1: 44 // ','
    2: 54 // '6'
    3: 48 // '0'
    4: 44 // ','
    5: 48 // '0'
    6: 44 // ','
    7: 54 // '6'
    8: 48 // '0'
  */
})();



